# ASP.NET MVC: The HttpApplication processes every request to the server including requests for css, js, img. Is it normal?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

There is a heavy mvc application and many styles, scipts, images into the every page.
But the HttpApplication processes an every request to the server including requests for .css, js, img. I assume it spends resources.

Can I turn off that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the other responses are a bit misleading so I'll chime in.

The setting that controls this behavior is the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` attribute located in the `configuration\system.webServer\modules` section of your Web.config file. Every MVC project template has that set to true by default. You could set it to false to disable the behavior.

**However**, note that this *might* cause your routes to stop working. That's because on earlier versions of IIS this setting was required to make routing work with extenionless URLs. Without this setting IIS used to treat such requests as if they referred to folders and would bypass the managed pipeline altogether. This setting forces IIS to run all managed modules for all requests (as the name of the setting eloquently implies), thus giving URL routing a chance to respond.

In Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (or other OS's that have [KB980368](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368) installed) this setting is no longer necessary.

So depending on the configuration of your servers you might be able to turn it off, but you should certainly test first to verify your application will continue to work.

Comment: Thank you for the detailted answer.

Comment: But changing this setting has no effect for me.

Comment: <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />
  </system.webServer>

Answer (score 1):

The resources need to be spent, or else IIS will not be able to send these files to the browser.

Requests to static files do not go through the dynamic request pipeline - they are bypassed, so shouldn't be a concern in this respect.

Comment: `The resources need to be spent`? Sent?

Comment: @Chris - _CPU_ and _memory_ resources need to be **spent**. The _files_ need to be **sent**.

Comment: valid statement then, really fitting with my answer since my answer is the solution to not use those resources.

Comment: All http modules including such as SessionStateModule are invoked during any request for me. I see that my database session provider gets sessions state from a database on every request for any static files. Is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a position to have legitimate concerns about the consumption of server hardware resources used to serve resource files on your application, the solution to that is to remove those resources from your application.

That is the entire purpose of a content distribution network.